Why am I getting a "Duplicate entry" error for an email that doesn't exist in my DB of the Laravel app?
I'm working on a Laravel project and encountered a strange issue when trying to insert a new user into the users table. The error I’m seeing is:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sahan12@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

What’s odd is that when I query the database, I can’t find any user with the email "sahan12@gmail.com". Here's a bit more context:

I'm using a migration to create the users table, and the email column is set to be unique.
I’ve also used Laravel's seeder to generate fake data in this table before attempting this insert.

Here's the migration for the users table:
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table-\>id();
$table-\>string('name');
$table-\>string('email')-\>unique();
$table-\>string('user_name')-\>unique()-\>nullable();
$table-\>string('phone')-\>unique()-\>nullable();
$table-\>timestamp('email_verified_at')-\>nullable();
$table-\>string('password');
$table-\>rememberToken();
$table-\>enum('role', \['student', 'teacher', 'admin'\]);
$table-\>boolean('is_active')-\>default(1);
$table-\>timestamps();
$table-\>softDeletes();
});

Here's my validation rules:
 public function rules(): array
    {
        $rules = [
            
            'user_name' => [
                'nullable',
                'string',
                Rule::unique('users', 'user_name'),
            ],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::unique('users', 'email'),
            ],
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

I tried querying the users table directly using Laravel's
DB::table('users')->where('email', 'sahan12@gmail.com')->first() 

to see if there was already a record with that email. I expected to find either a matching record or no results at all. However, the query returned null, indicating that no user with this email exists, yet the "Duplicate entry" error persists when I attempt to insert a new record.
My Questions:

Why is Laravel/MySQL throwing a "Duplicate entry" error for an email that appears not to exist in the database?
How can I troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

I’m really stuck on this and would appreciate any help or pointers!

You're using soft deletes, so I'd guess that you have a "deleted" row where email = 'sahan12@gmail.com' and deleted_at is not null, and that row is being transparently excluded from search results but it still conflicting for the unique constraint.

@AlexHowansky, I'd disagree since the DB::table('users')->where('email', 'sahan12@gmail.com')->first() query does not use soft deletes, only eloquent models use soft delete. The table might have a soft delete column, but the DB::table() query would still return the row even if it is soft deleted
